# what is the best way to check if a string is date value?

Tags: go, reflection

Reflection does not seem to be working for time. What is the best approach here?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    stringDate := "07/26/2020"

    // parse string date to golang time
    t, _ := time.Parse("01/02/2006", stringDate)

    ts := ""

    ts = t.String()

    v := reflect.ValueOf(ts)

    fmt.Println(ts) // prints "2020-07-26 00:00:00 +0000 UTC"

    fmt.Println(v.Type()) //  prints "string". How do I get this to time.Time ?

}
```

Comment: You mean if a string contains a "valid" date? "Valid" is relative, it depends on a specific layout. To tell if a string is a valid date based on a specific layout, try to parse it using `time.Parse()`, and do check the returned error.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `time.Parse` you are checking already if the `stringDate` is a valid date and you are parsing it to `time.Time`. What you really need is to check for `err` when parsing the date.

Example:

```
stringDate := "not a date"

// parse string date to golang time
t, err := time.Parse("01/02/2006", stringDate)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

fmt.Println("Time: ", t, "Type of t: ", reflect.ValueOf(t).Type())
```

Which would print out

```
parsing time "not a date" as "01/02/2006": cannot parse "not a date" as "01"
```

But providing a valid date will result in printing out:

```
Time:  2012-03-07 00:00:00 +0000 UTC Type of t:  time.Time
```

The working example you can find [here](https://go.dev/play/p/NXgoH_S4otu)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do it:

```
package main
import "time"

func isDateValue(stringDate string) bool {
   _, err := time.Parse("01/02/2006", stringDate)
   return err == nil
}

func main() {
   ok := isDateValue("07/26/2020")
   println(ok)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).